# Showing a dynamically built div

Tags: php, jquery

I have a drop-down menu built from entries in a database. What I need to do is to show certain content based on the selected entry in the menu. So, if I choose "Apples" in the menu, I can write a query to pull "Apple" info out of the database and the content div will show this information. "Oranges" will write an "Oranges" query and then show the info on oranges.

Ideally, I'd like the index of the selected menu item. But since I'm not submitting any form, I cannot get the info from `$_POST` variables.  I could get it via jQuery or Javascript but I need it for processing another MySQL statement.

Since I don't know the information in the menu, I can't set up specific `div`s to show the content.

Hopefully this makes sense! Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you not use jQuery's .change method? When the dropdown value is changed, send an ajax post, to get the data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AJAX. My searches mentioned this often and I was afraid it would come down to me trying to figure out how to do it that way.

Comment: If you want to do this type of thing, you have to bite the bullet and learn AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an asynchronous call. You want JavaScript triggered on the form changing to make a call to the server. On the server, you perform the SQL query and return it in a machine readable format such as JSON or just build the div on the server. When the JavaScript gets the  reply from the server, it can parse the contents and insert it into the page.

Answer (score 0):

I can sense you need an example

JQUERY:

```
    $('select').change(function(){
        var myfruit = $(this).val();  // apple, orange

        $.ajax({
            "url": yourphpfile.php,
            "type": "POST",
            "data":{"fruit":myfruit},
            }).success(function(response) {
            // response is what we get back from php

                for(var i in response){
                     $('#div').append(response[i]['fruit'];
                }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['fruit'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruit = '{$_POST['fruit']}'";
    // do something with your query, and get a result;
    echo json_encode($result);  // this gets sent to your jquery
    die;
}
```

Comment: So the $_POST works even though there isn't a form being submitted??